# Pass parameter to JQuery method

Tags: jquery

I have a list of objects and I loop over it and display a value from that list to the user using a straight HTML `<label>` into my Free Marker.

With each single loop, I render a button that is supposed to take that property which is previously rendered.

I do the following :

```
[#list myObjectList as object]
<label>  ${object.parameterA} </label>
<label>  ${object.parameterB} </label>
<input type="button" id="[@spring.url '/myUrl'/]"
                     class="testBtn btn testPassParameter"
                     value="Test the method" 
</input>
[/#list]

$('.testPassParameter').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            //Here I need to do some sort of magic to
            //fetch the value of  {object.parameterA} 
            }
     }
});
```

I tried to use div and assign a dynamic value as an ID to that div instead of using `<label>`
Then I can get the value from that div using `getElementById()`.
However, how could I get the element ID as I'm looping over a list and I need that particular property value?

Comment: Could you show the rendered html of (relevant part of) the page? jQuery, and (almost) all JavaScript, works client-side; on the DOM, therefore it's easier to answer the question when we know what it's working with.

Comment: Your HTML is mangled, in the linked demo you seem to have a `table` within an `a` element and both within an `h2`. You've not closed one of the table-rows towards the end. Could you explain step-by-step what you want to happen in response to what event(s)?

Comment: Hi David,Sorry for that mangled code.Here is a modified version:http://jsfiddle.net/WMdDZ/

Comment: And when clicking the button you want to alert the 'value' of `ParamB`?

Comment: I have observed that if you put the labels next to the button within the same <td> , it would work normally.:http://jsfiddle.net/WMdDZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts of an approach to this problem:

```
$('.testJQuery').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {
        var values = {}; // creating an object

        // looking at all table rows except for the one containing the button
        $('tr').not($(this).closest('tr')).each(
            function(){
                // the first 'label' is the label-text
                l = $(this).find('label:eq(0)').text();

                // the second 'label' is the value (for some reason)
                v = $(this).find('label:eq(1)').text();

                values[l] = v;
            });

        // using the console to allow for exploration of the returned object
        console.log(values);

        // just to prevent submission
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WMdDZ/1/).

This approach is somewhat unwieldy, given that it has to look at *every* table-row and then look for `label`s. In your finished version will there be one label-value pair per table? Or multiples?

If there's more than one pair per table what do you want to happen?

Incidentally, a `label` is used to uniquely identify an associated input element in a form; if you don't have an associated `input` you're using `label`s incorrectly. If you used, instead:

```
<td class="labelValuePairs">
    <span class="label">ParamB:</span>
    <span class="value">ParamB value</span>
</td>
```

It becomes slightly easier to work with, for example:

```
$('.testJQuery').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {

        var table = $(this).closest('table'),
            labelText = table.find('.labelValuePairs span.label').text(),
            valueText = table.find('.labelValuePairs span.value').text();

        alert(labelText + ' ' + valueText);

        return false;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WMdDZ/2/).

It's worth noting that you don't need to iterate over the `$('.testJQuery')` elements with `each()`, the `click()` method will apply to all elements returned by the selector. The above, then, can be reduced to:

```
$('.testJQuery').click(function(event) {

    var table = $(this).closest('table'),
        labelText = table.find('.labelValuePairs span.label').text(),
        valueText = table.find('.labelValuePairs span.value').text();

    alert(labelText + ' ' + valueText);

    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WMdDZ/3/).

Comment: Actually your answer is just amazing.However,I am tring to find more geneic solotion to look for a table I specify instead of using "closest()" by giving an id to the table:http://jsfiddle.net/BuS3r/

Comment: Thanks David Thomas for your support.

Answer (score 1):

add a class to your parameter A element to:

```
<label class="parameterA">  ${object.parameterA} </label>
```

change your JS to:

```
$('.testPassParameter').click(function() {
    var parameterA = $(this).prev(".parameterA:eq(0)").text();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I try this approach , I got an empty "var parameterA" though it renders with a value.

Comment: Kindly check my piece of code into the following url.I still have the issue to include your approach into my work. http://jsfiddle.net/LwbzX/

Comment: Here is a modified version:jsfiddle.net/WMdDZ

Answer (score 1):

Within your click method use `$.prev` to access a previous sibling.

```
$('.testPassParameter').each(function() {

        $(this).click(function(event) {
            //Here I need to do some sort of magic to
            //fetch the value of  {object.parameterA}
            console.log($(this).prev().text()); // access text of label
         });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EjebG/2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EjebG/8/.  Use `$.prev` again.  To get the prev sibling of the the 2nd label.

Comment: Hello Trevor,Kindly check my piece of code into the following url.I still have the issue to include your approach into my work. http://jsfiddle.net/LwbzX/

Comment: Here is a modified version:jsfiddle.net/WMdDZ